# Trying to hide some custom fields on Lead in Edit Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, visibility

I have few Custom fields on Lead. And i wanted them to be visible on Detail page but hidden on Edit page Layout.   So i made those fields "Read Only" from Layout of Lead. But to my surprise those read Only fields are still visible on Edit/Create New Lead pages.

Anybody knows what am i doing wrong? OR its not possible to hide a field on edit page layout of Lead. (without creating formula field or VF page)?

ps. I am trying this with Custom Profile.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It should work, and you don't need to create special VF/formula for that. Does the field is open for edit  or you just see their label but without value? The former is the expected, if it is still open for edit then maybe check the profile for the custom profile that your are using. +Try to clear cache (open in incognito tab) as sometime layout properties are cached

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking using your system admin profile, you might have the "Edit Read Only Fields Permissions". Try with a different standard profile and see whether you can see the same results.

Comment: I have tried this with Custom Profile...

Comment: Maybe the layout you have put the fields as read only has not been assigned to the record type of the record you are currently looking at. Are you working with record types?

Comment: No record types on lead.